# DRF simple jwt getting auth token from a user instance OR change username and password combination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I have a chat app that uses the same authentication method as in WhatsApp.

Normally I would get the jwt auth token with this:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainView
path('api/token/', TokenObtainView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

However This asks for both username and password while my user model is using phone_number and a validation code instead. Is there any way to change this?

username ======> phone_number
password ======> phone_code (The validation code)

The second way
Is to pass the user instance and get the auth token from it somehow

my Login view

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def loginuser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone_number = request.data.get('phone_number')
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
            if int(request.data.get('phone_code')) == user.phone_code and user.phone_code:
                # user.phone_code = None
                # user.save()
                return Response({'phone_number': phone_number}, status.HTTP_200_OK)

            else:
                return Response({'error': "Invalid code"}, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except Exception as error:
                return Response({'error': error}, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

my user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=20)
    about = models.CharField(
        max_length=190, default="Hi, I use Orgachat!", blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    phone_code = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)

# Save auth token, I know this should be in signals.py but whatever    
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to write your custom backend class and add it to Django this is intended to allow different ways to authenticate, [see](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/)

Also, you can inherit from `TokenObtainView` and add your logic there and use this custom class instead, but I prefer to integrate the first option with JWT so you need to read the docs and see how it works.

I just realised that `django-rest-framework-jwt` tag is there, you should drop using this package as it's [unmaintained](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/484), use [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) instead

Answer (score 5):

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken, SlidingToken, UntypedToken
from django.conrtib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.first()
SlidingToken.for_user(user)
RefreshToken.for_user(user)
str(RefreshToken.for_user(user))
str(RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token)
```

You can get the user jwt token from user instance using this. Hope this will work for you.